# To which point is a paper considered as a "student contribution"?

Tags: phd, paper-submission

I am a PhD student, in the process of submitting a paper and I was asked to check (or not check) a box to state if :

> This contribution was solely written by students and/or doctoral candidates.

This paper was solely written by me as first author, with my supervisors as co-authors for reviewing. It deals mostly with measurements and their interpretation, which were done by me exclusively, the only non-original content is a figure I'm citing from another paper. However, my supervisors reviewed this paper, and also gave me advice during the research.

Is this sentence to be interpreted drastically (meaning I should not check it since the work is done by a supervised student, and not student(s) exclusively). And in a more general way, to which point would a paper be no longer considered as "student contribution" ?

This may seem obvious but I'm not familiar with publications processes since it's the first time I submit something.

Comment: This is usually used for deciding canidates for "best student award" which is for papers where ALL co-authors are students. So, if your supervisor is a co-author then "This contribution was solely written by students and/or doctoral candidates" does not apply to you.

Comment: @Alexandros Some sub-fields of CS allow faculty coauthors on "best student paper" winners, as long as the student is first author.  Others (like my own) do not.

Comment: It seems to depend a lot on the subject area. In mine, the answer would very clearly be yes, it would be considered a student paper. You have to be the main author and done the majority of the work. It goes without saying that the supervisor/advisor is on the paper too - of course he is! What's important is that a student is *the* main contributor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, such declarations are typically defined in terms of authorship.  Thus, you will see, for example, a prize to be awarded for papers with a student first author, or for papers with only students as authors.

I would therefore generally interpret "solely written by" as meaning "all co-authors are."

If you want to be certain, however, it should not be any problem to request clarification from the organizers.

Comment: Is that why they ask that question? Do journals give out awards for papers authored only by students?

Comment: Conferences certainly do; I don't know of journals that do, but some might.